# Border sizing glitch while content is loading

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with the size of my border being incorrect before the content of the border (a video) is loaded. I have a list of elements and each element can be clicked - this will load a new video (animation) for each different element. Because there can be a short loading time for the videos, sometimes they take 1-2 seconds to appear. During this time, the border size is way off and overlaps my other elements. As soon as the video loads, the border 'snaps' to the correct size.

How do I keep my border from doing this?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="video"><video id="animation" autoplay="" loop="" muted=""><source src="videos/xxxxxxx.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#animation{
border: 5px solid #c00;
height: 100%;
}

#video{
height: 50%;
}
```

And here's a photo of the issue (I've painted over the text of the website). Note the way too large and overlapping border before the video loads.

[image: issue example]

Please let me know if there's any extra info or code I can provide.

Comment: Have you tried setting a width in css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is set the width of the video to something fixed.
    #video{ width:300px;}
     #video video{width:100%;}

Comment: So simple. Thank you.